# Why do I keep getting a "Cannot find '...' in scope" error?

Tags: swift, swiftui, scope, binding

I am trying to make a second view on an app which is like a leaderboard. When the game has completed 10 rounds on ContentView, I want the calculated score to be stored and printed on the ScoreboardView (accessed by a button). I used @Binding to connect the score variable from one view to the other, but keep getting the "out of scope" error. Does anyone know why this is? Here is my code for the ScoreboardView:

'''

```
import SwiftUI

struct scoreboardView: View {
    @Binding var score: Int
    var body: some View {
            List {
                ForEach(1..<9) {
                    Text("Game \($0): \(score) ")
                }
            }
        }
    
}

struct scoreboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        scoreboardView(score: $scoreTracker)
        }
}
```

'''

This is not my final code, therefore ignore the middle. However, I get the error in the last line of the initializing of the preview.

Comment: Cannot find what? The precise error message, and  the precise location where it occurs, would be helpful.

Comment: @MartinR It says "Cannot find scoreTracker in scope". I declared scoreTracker in my contentView and was trying to connect it to the "score" variable here, yet it gave me that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have anything defined called `scoreTracker` in your code, but you're trying to use it in your preview. Instead, you can pass a constant in place of your binding (just for preview purposes):

```
struct scoreboardView: View {
    @Binding var score: Int
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(1..<9) {
                Text("Game \($0): \(score) ")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct scoreboardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        scoreboardView(score: .constant(50))
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, but scoreTracker is the name of the variable in ContentView that is connected to "score" through @Binding. Shouldn't it work in that case?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. As you can see, your `scoreboardView_Previews` has no connection to `ContentView`. All it does is load `scoreboardView`. The typical way to handle this situation is exactly what I showed -- use a `constant`. In your `ContentView` preview, your binding will get passed assuming that `scoreboardView` is a child of `ContentView` in the view hierarchy.

Comment: I am a little confused. So if I were to run my app rather than previewing it, the constant I set in "scoreboardView_Previews" shouldn't matter, correct? Also, could you please rephrase your last sentence of your answer? I didn't quite understand.

Comment: Correct, if you are not in preview mode, it doesn’t matter.

Comment: If this answered your question, you can mark it as correct with the green check mark

Comment: Thank you. Also, do you mind checking out my other questions? Haven't gotten answers on them yet.